# como puedo hacer una lista seleccionando los elementos de otra lista?

Tags: lista, bucle-for, condiciones

tengo una pregunta.
quiero hacer 2 listas a partir de una lista.  quiero que cada elemento de la lista: list0, sea el lugar donde hay un 0 en: list, es decir: quiero que me devuelva: [3,6,7] y quiero que la otra lista:listno0, me devuelva los lugares de los elementos de lista que no son 0. esto es: [0,1,2,4,5,8].
por ahora solo puedo hacer que me devuelva los valores, pero no los lugares donde se encuentran esos valores. el codigo de abajo me devuelve: list0=[0,0,0] y listno0=[8,9,7,6,7,11]

```
list=[8,9,7,0,6,7,0,0,11]
list0=[]
listno0=[]
 
for i in list:
if i==0:
    list0.append(i)
else: 
    listno0.append(i)
    
print(list0)
print(listno0)
```

si pongo por ejemplo list0.append(list[i]), me da siempre el primer valor de la lista list y si pongo por ejemplo list0.append(list[i==0])tampoco funciona. alguna idea?
grcias!

Comment: Nombrar una lista como `list` puede ser peligroso puesto que [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) ya existe y es una clase de python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener ese comportamiento si usas [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). De esta forma, dentro del mismo ciclo for puedes usar tanto el valor (que es lo que quieres comparar) como el índice de ese valor (que es lo que quieres guardar). Un ejemplo

```py
list=[8,9,7,0,6,7,0,0,11]
list0=[]
listno0=[]

# value - contiene un valor de la lista
# i     - contiene el indice que corresponde con ese valor
for i, value in enumerate(list):
    if value == 0:
        list0.append(i)
    else: 
        listno0.append(i)
    
print(list0)
print(listno0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ha ocurrido que puedes hacer es poner una variable antes del for y que vayas incrementando dentro.

```
    lista=[8,9,7,0,6,7,0,0,11]
    list0=[]
    listno0=[]
    
    c = 0
    for i in lista:

        if i==0:
            list0.append(c)
        else: 
            listno0.append(c)
        c = c +1
    print(list0)
    print(listno0)
```

Seguramente haya otra forma de hacerlo, pero con esta, saca justamente lo que quieres.